# How to Add id attribute to a tag in orchard alternates

Tags: orchardcms

I use `Orchard CMS 1.10.1`. I have created an alternate for a menu, I know how to add a `class attribute` to a tag

```
var tag = Tag(Model, "ul");
tag.AddCssClass("class-custom");
```

I need to add an `id attrubite` to this `ul` tag. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use one of the following methods to add custom attributes:

1. **Add attribute to shape before create the tag:**

```cs
Model.Attributes.Add("id", "blah");
var tag = Tag(Model, "ul");
```

2. **Add attributes after create tag:**

```cs
var tag = Tag(Model, "ul");
tag.MergeAttribute("id", "blah");
```

3. **Add "Id" attribute to shape (only applicable for id attribute):**

```cs
Model.Id = "blah";
var tag = Tag(Model, "ul");
```